# Highcharts chart x axis labels are missing when screen is compressed to 1280*1024 resolution

Tags: highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/yu738h0m/ `Labels are displayed on normal resolutions when you compress screen to 1280*1024 x-axis labels are missing`

Comment: Hi, it looks like there simply isnt enough room to display the characters of the monthname, so i would suggest changing the font size or descriptions when screen size gets to small. Change first monthname 'Jan' to 'J' and you will see this still fits.

Comment: if you inspect the element, you can see that labels are not rendered on the chart, so changing styles doesn't affect anything. I tried changing month name from Jan to J, even then it's not working.